# How to simulate a cellular automaton via a Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, turing-completeness, cellular-automata

It is rather easy to see that every cellular automaton can be simulated by a Turing machine: We can simulate a cellular automaton with an appropriate C program and every C program can be simulated by a Turing machine. But how would a concrete TM look like which simulates a CA?

Comment: Iterate over first generation, check the values of any three neighboring cells and use that to decide the next value of the middle cell. Use some sort of end markers to know when you're done. Then iterate back, replacing first generation with second generation. Rinse and repeat. Is there something specifically unclear about it?

Comment: What confuses me a bit is the following: There is an potentially infinite number of cells which change their state during one step of the CA. If we simulate the parallel change of all of these cells sequentially, then the TM needs an infinite amount of time to simulate the first step of the CA and never proceeds to the second step of the CA.

Comment: A C program would also be unable to deal with that problem! A CA that starts with only finitely many cells "on" can only change finitely many cells at each generation.

Comment: Does this mean that CAs are more powerful than TMs, at least if I specify an infinite beginning configuration?

Comment: Yes, the halting problem can be solved in certain neural networks, which can be simulated by CA. http://books.google.de/books?id=6o6zx5MRRcQC&lpg=PA437&ots=n1XxSv8N9u&dq=cellular%20automata%20powerful%20turing%20machine&hl=de&pg=PA437#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Note however that CA with certain "infinite" starting configurations (infinite number of "on" cells and "off" cells) can still be simulated by a TM, e.g when [almost all](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost) cells in all generations follow a pattern which can be finitely encoded.

Comment: That surprises me. Isn't this at least a bit a contradiction to the Church-Turing thesis?

Comment: Whether or not this contradicts the CTT is kind of a controversy. After all the CTT is just a thesis, not a theorem. An argument that CTT still holds is that all [super-Turing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercomputation) models include something, that is not effectivly computable in terms of the CTT, e.g. computing an infinite amount of information in finite time, like in your case. Consider opening a new question for follow-up questions, since the comments arent made for lengthy discussions.